# $ sign in url from text file gives error while download via wget

Tags: bash, unix, wget

I want to download files with wget in a bash script. The url's look like this:
https://xxx.blob.core.windows.net/somefolder/$somefile.webm?sv=xxx&sp=r..

Problem is the $ doller sign in the url

When I download the file with double quotes I get a 403 because the $ sign is probably interpreted.

`wget "https://xxx.blob.core.windows.net/somefolder/$somefile.webm?sv=xxx&sp=r.."`

When I single quote the url and download the file everything goes well:

`wget 'https://xxx.blob.core.windows.net/somefolder/$somefile.webm?sv=xxx&sp=r..'`

But the url should come from a line in a text file. So I read the file and pass the lines as url:

```bash
files=($(< file.txt))

# Read through the url.txt file and execute wget command for every filename
while IFS='=| ' read -r param uri; do 
    for file in "${files[@]}"; do
        wget "${file}"
    done
done < file.txt
```

I get the 403 here as well and don't know how to prevent the termimal from interpreting the dollar sign. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Use single quotes, not double quotes, to surround a string wherein a `$` should be literal.

Comment: The `$` should not be interpreting through a variable.  Can you print the url contents? (change `wget` to `echo`).  That should make the issue more obvious.

Comment: You're not using `param` and `uri` for anything?

Comment: Beyond that, `files=( $(...anything...) )` is inherently buggy; see [BashPitfalls #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#hosts.3D.28_.24.28aws_.2BICY.29_.29) -- if you want to populate an array with lines from a file, use `readarray -t files <file.txt`

Comment: That said, your script itself _doesn't_ run `wget "..."` the way your examples show (those examples briefly led me to mistakenly close the question as a duplicate, before taking a closer look and realizing they were irrelevant to your real problem): `"$file"` passes the variable's exact contents with no further interpretation, unlike the interpretation you would get if you put the variable's contents inside those same quotes in the source code.

Comment: Run `set -x` to enable logging, and compare actual and intended behaviors. If you have a working wget command you can run by hand, compare what `set -x` logs for that working command to what it logs when you run `bash -x yourscript`.

Comment: See: [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/3776858)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But the url should come from a line in a text file.

If you have file with 1 URL per line or are able to easily alter your file to hold 1 URL per line, then you might use `-i file` option, from [`wget` man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/wget)

> -i file
>
> --input-file=file
>
> Read URLs from a local or external file. If - is specified as file, URLs are read from the standard input. (Use ./- to
> read from a file literally named -.)
>
> If this function is used, no URLs need be present on the command line.
> If there are URLs both on the command line and in an input file, those
> on the command lines will be the first ones to be retrieved. If
> --force-html is not specified, then file should consist of a series of URLs, one per line.(...)

So if you have single file, say `urls.txt` you might use it like so

```
wget -i urls.txt
```

and if you have few files you might concat them and shove through standard input like so

```
cat urls1.txt urls2.txt urls3.txt | wget -i -
```

If file(s) contain additional data then remember to process them so GNU `wget` will get only URLs.

Comment: Simple as that. Thanks a lot!